Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from fail to requesting from FastAPI
My FastAPI main function code below:
class Prompt(BaseModel):
    content: str = ""

@app.post("/query")
def query_item(prompt: Prompt = None):
   return promt

when I try to send my post request using curl
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8000/query"  -d '{"content":"Hello"}'
the response shows Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from
Need help
I tried to use requests package and send exlicit dict in request but the issue remains

Have you tried removing = None? None is not a valid dictionary.

In addition to the link provided above, please have a look at this answer as well.

You need to tell curl to use application/json as the content type:
λ curl -X POST "http://localhost:8111/query" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"content\":\"Hello\"}"
{"content":"Hello"}

(and you need to change return promt to return prompt)
